# What are the duties of the coach in a football team?

Tags: football

This question came up in our exams. The Laws don't mention duties of the coach. I understand they aren't supposed to mention everything. But, there must be some common duties of the football coaches of different leagues and tournaments.

What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about *head coach* as management team of football club can have other coaches like fitness coach, goalkeeper coach and like. See: [Chelsea FC management team](http://www.chelseafc.com/teams/management-team.html)

Responsibilities of a head coach in a professional football club usually include (but are not limited to) the following:

1. Selecting the team of players for matches, and their formation.
2. Planning the strategy, and instructing the players on the pitch.
3. Motivating players before and during a match.
4. Scouting for young players for eventual training in the youth academy or the reserves, and encouraging their development and improvement.
5. Facing the media in pre-match and post-match interviews.
6. Delegating duties to other [coaching and medical staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaching_staff).*

*[The management of the team (coaching and medical staff) might be under the club board](http://www.essentiallysports.com/manager-vs-head-coach-real-boss/).

For more information read [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coach_(sport)#Association_football).

---

<sub>References:

1. [Manager (association football)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manager_(association_football))

2. [What is the difference between a manager and a coach in case of a soccer team?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17437/what-is-the-difference-between-a-manager-and-a-coach-in-case-of-a-soccer-team)</sub>